# Structure AngularJS code into WAR package

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tomcat, war

I want to create WAR package with AngularJS code:

[image]

I imported .js files from resources directory this way:

```
<script src="resources/vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

But I'm not aware how I Can import .js files from Javascript code:

```
<script>
      System.import('resources/system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the JS to be in the WEB-INF directory because the browser won't be able to request files in that directory (unless you have something on the server that will intercept requests for "/resources" and read the files from that directory). It looks like you also have the JS code in the "/public" directory so your JS files should be loaded from there.

```
<script src="public/vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
  System.import('public/system-config.js').then(function () {
    System.import('main');
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: it's not working. I get ReferenceError: System is not defined
 

System.import('public/system-config.js').then(function () {